# Run PHP MySQL web application on Android

Tags: web-server

I want to run a PHP MySQL web application on an Android device. The device is not rooted.

Is there any way? If there isn't, can the device connect to a PC's localhost offline?

Comment: Use an app that provides your needs. There are several [web servers with scripting support](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_server_web#group_414) available (disclosure: link goes to my Android site).

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE AS OF JUNE 2, 2021


Option #1 ( Using CLI-based apks)

BEST OPTION**

1. [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux)
   (Installation of [PHP](https://parzibyte.me/blog/en/2019/04/28/install-apache-php-7-android-termux/amp/), [MARIADB](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/MariaDB), [PHPMYADMIN](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/5715) packages within termux)
2. [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm)
3. [UserLand](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tech.ula)

**Option #2 (Using GUI-based apks)**

1. [KSWEB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.kslabs.ksweb)
2. [Servers Ultimate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.serversultimate)

**Summary:**

- The above-mentioned apks do not require rooted device.
- **CLI-based apks** are highly recommended because a user can use **UPDATED** version of *PHP*, *Apache*, and any other packages you want to install to. The **KickWeb apk** does support running .php files **BUT**
  ,unfortunately, it doesn't have the latest PHP VERSION. Using an outdated version of PHP makes some of your PHP code to throw errors or warnings etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried [KickWeb Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nokshaserv) and it works as expected.